# Error to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a Spring boot java application with a Mysql database. But when I changed the parameter in the "application.properties" file, no change on my application run so I deleted my configuration on my starting dashboard on Slipse but now I cannot start the connection to my database.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=2MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=2MB


server.port=8081
server.servlet.session.timeout=1200
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.storage.storage_engine=innodb

spring.resources.add-mappings=true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

```
2021-05-20 16:11:58.261  INFO 7432 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-05-20 16:11:58.353  INFO 7432 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 84 ms. Found 11 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-05-20 16:11:58.842  INFO 7432 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-05-20 16:11:58.849  INFO 7432 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-05-20 16:11:58.850  INFO 7432 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.43]
2021-05-20 16:11:58.944  INFO 7432 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-05-20 16:11:58.944  INFO 7432 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1275 ms
2021-05-20 16:11:59.042  WARN 7432 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2021-05-20 16:11:59.046  INFO 7432 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-05-20 16:11:59.063  INFO 7432 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-05-20 16:11:59.076 ERROR 7432 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Comment: I'm confused. You deleted your configuration and are now surprised that it's missing?

Comment: I have deleted my configuration because I change the name dbb but use the same. hand now it try to use but not working. How fixed that.